# Adding a "background-image" change to existing jquery css change afterwards

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

I have a link which has...

```
a#popup { background:url(../popupopen.jpg) center right no-repeat #fff;
```

which toggles a menu position using...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('a#popup').toggle(function () {
jQuery("#wps-sidebar").css({left: "30px"});
}, function () {
jQuery("#wps-sidebar").css({left: "-240px"});
});
});
```

& I'm trying to add a simple background image change to the end of each, so that when it opens the background image changes to use popupclose.jpg (after the menu position toggle), & obviously back to popupopen.jpg once it's closed again.  I'm trying to copy existing examples but can't find anything that gets through to my js-inept brain, can someone please advise?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd suggest adding and removing class, and you can prescribe what images you want in the a#popupwiththisimage, a#popoutwiththisimage or a#popupwiththatimage

Comment: Would that be the more elegant way to go about it?  As is probably obvious I'm just learning js/jQuery from a css/html background.
To be honest I'm not sure how I'd add that to the current jQuery gubbins above either...

Comment: Actually yes thank you, just the tip I needed.
I applied the background to the sidebar instead, & just used addClass/removeClass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applied the background to #wps-sidebar instead of a#popup, then...

```
#wps-sidebar.opened {
left: 30px;
background: url(../popupclose.jpg) center right no-repeat #fff;
}
```

...&...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('a#popup').toggle(function () {
jQuery("#wps-sidebar").addClass("opened");
}, function () {
jQuery("#wps-sidebar").removeClass("opened");
});
});
```

Thank you for the suggestion, just the brain-slap I needed. :)